# Filepath comparsion in MySQL

Tags: mysql, filepath, string-comparison

I am executing a MySQL query

```
select * 
from table 
where filepath LIKE '/Videos/ABC-Copy.mp4'
```

but I am getting zero rows as a result even though an exact same value exists in filepath column...

I have also tried using "//" in the query but am getting zero rows as result.

What am I missing ?

Comment: actually mysql have a bug or mysql not able to understand '/' in data .so in your path replace '/' with '///'. that will work for you

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal, can you please give an example of values to have in the table and in the LIKE part of the query

Comment: What if you use `LIKE '%/Videos/ABC-Copy.mp4%'`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using like, it's common to use the '%' character. Otherwise you don't need like. You can just do an equal.

For example what your above query actually does is.

```
select * from table where filepath =  '/Videos/ABC-Copy.mp4'
```

What you want is

```
 select * from table where filepath LIKE '%/Videos/ABC-Copy.mp4'
```

Answer (score 0):

try with % symbol..

```
select * from table where filepath LIKE '%/Videos/ABC-Copy.mp4'
```